# Online Indent with 2,3,4 spaces, indent of Ruby code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

Is there any website available to Online Indent with 2,3,4 spaces indent of Ruby code?
Is there any online tool for HAML too?

as like for JavaScript there is http://jsbeautifier.org/

Comment: This question is not clear, and also does not appear to be on-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: haml is already 'beautified' by default... If it isn't your haml code doesn't work...

Comment: what about Ruby? and HAML will work if it is "beautified"... :)
I wish to get any site which work like http://jsbeautifier.org/ for Ruby/HAML..etc

Comment: In HAML the 'code beautify' isn't just an aesthetic thing, it is part of the code logic and behavior, and that is the thing you have to do yourself!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you search for 'ruby beautifier' in google you'll find several options. Including a textmate plugin: https://github.com/mocoso/code-beautifier.tmbundle